# Angular Select show a different text once selected

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS (1.5) and im trying to create a select dropdown that can display a different text when selected vs shown in dropdown options

Option example {id: 1, name: 'text', selected: 'this was selected'}

Given the example above, how can i show the name property when they open the dropdown but the selected property after the option is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options for dropdowns in angularjs. If you're going the `ng-repeat` route, then if you have an array of objects structured like your example, then this would work:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="item.selected"> {{item.name}} </option>
</select>
```

This will display the "name" in the dropdown, but since value=item.selected, it will assign the "selected" value to your `ng-model`.

Alternatively, you can do `ng-options` for the select and something like this would work:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
    ng-options="item.selected as item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

This does the same thing, but `ng-options` tends to allow more flexibility as you can assign entire objects to your model rather than just strings like `ng-repeat` only allows, plus angular claims it's faster.

Hope this helps. See here for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select